Is there a bug in ocgx2?
When this document is compiled twice in a row, the angle measurement (38) should not be displayed, but it is.
It should be displayed by clicking on the angle.
This was not a problem this summer.
What is the problem?
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}                     
    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Mesure l'angle ci-dessous:}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,font=\scriptsize]
%38°
\draw[draw=white,switch ocg=hg] (60:4)coordinate(x)--(0,0)coordinate(O)--(98:4)coordinate(y);
\draw (x)--(O)--(y);
\pic[angle radius=15mm,draw,%pic text=\ang{38},
fill=gray!20, angle eccentricity=1.2]{angle=x--O--y};
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=hg,ref=hg,status=invisible}]
\pic[angle radius=10mm,pic text=38,angle eccentricity=.8]{angle=x--O--y};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



For me, it seems to work as expected. If I click on the angle, the initially hidden number "38" becomes visible. Could you please check that your TeX installation is up to date? You may put \listfiles at the top of the input and post the file list from the end of the log file here.

@AlexG I have the latest version of MikTeX. Which was packaged on 31 August 2024. In the log, it says version 0.58.

That is two weeks ago. In the meantime I updated pdfbase (part of media9) which is a dependency. Would you please download pdfbase.sty into the working directory and try again? (Btw, TeXLive is usually faster with updates from upstream CTAN.)

@AlexG Thank you very much, it works perfectly now!

I’m voting to close this question because the problem is solved in the comments
